# Generic Type conversion in Python

Tags: .net, python

How can I perform a generic type conversion in python similar to the following mechanism that I use in C# .NET:

```
string typetoConvertTo = "System.String";
string value = (string)Convert.ChangeType( "1", Type.GetType( typetoConvertTo ));

typetoConvertTo = "System.Int32";
int value1 = (int)Convert.ChangeType( "1", Type.GetType(typetoConvertTo));
```

Python has type conversion for individual types, but I need something more generic like the above method in .NET since I am storing the type and need to perform a generic conversion later.

```
value = str(100)
value1 = int("100")
```

Answer (score 6):

Classes are first-class objects in Python.

```
>>> t = str
>>> t(123)
'123'
>>> d = {'str': str}
>>> d['str'](123)
'123'
```

Comment: hmm. Not sure if this is generic because in my case, the value - str you used in the first line is coming from a database.

Comment: the `'str'` value used to index the dictionary is the value coming from your database.  It could be `'super duper string'` instead giving `d = {'super duper string': str}` and `d['super duper string'](123)`.  `d` is just your type/conversion lookup mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to delay type conversions for some reason, just store the value and the type conversion as a pair.

```
>>> entry = (int, '123')
>>> entry[0](entry[1])
123
```

If you had a whole batch of them to do, you could have something like

```
conversions_to_do = {}
conversions_to_do[int] = []
conversions_to_do[str] = []
conversions_to_do[int].append('123')
conversions_to_do[int].append('456')
conversions_to_do[str].append(1.86)
```

Unwrapping it is similar to the first example.

I have to ask though, why not just convert it directly?  There may be a simpler and more straightforward way to tackle the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The type to convert to is actually stored in a database in string format. So when I need to perform operations on it, I prefer a generic conversion instead of a giant switch loop based on that value.

Comment: Somewhere, there is going to be a lookup that maps the string type into a class.  A type lookup dictionary `type_lookup = {'int':int, 'string':str, etc, etc}` and then using `type_lookup[type_string](value)` to perform the conversion may be what you're after instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a type-mapping dict and can instead use `eval`, but that's almost like cheating:

```
>>> t = "int"
>>> v = "3"
>>> eval(t)(v)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking to solve the same problem, then I tried this, and it works. If you still didn't find the solution, this just worked for me:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar("T")

def my_method(input, cast_type: Type[T]) -> T:
    print(type(input))
    print(input)

    casted_value = cast_type(input)

    print(type(casted_value))
    print(casted_value)

    return casted_value

my_method(12)
```

This prints me out the following:

```
<class 'int'>
12
<class 'float'>
12.0
```